Printing residues in a selection in Pymol?
I am currently working on a protein where I have selected residues within 10A of its bound ligand in pymol. However, I can not find a way to print out what residues are contained in that group of residues that are within 10A.
So far, I have tried this:
print or output the selected residues in pymol
specifically,
iterate selected and name CA, print (resi, resn)
However, after cross-referencing the residues printed with those that I can see selected in the pdb file sequence, this method omits many of the residues.
Does anyone have a pymol command line they have used to accomplish this?

how do you select the interacting residues ? Are you sure the command you use returns a selection of residues and not just a selection of atoms , in this case maybe you get the side chains and not the CAs

Here is my attempt; from pymol console:
fetch 5NLM

remove chain B

remove solvent

select ios , resn ios  ---> LIGAND

select 10atoms, chain A within 10 of  ios  --> selection "10atoms" defined with 695 atoms.

ls = []

iterate 10atoms, ls.append((resi, resn))

print(ls)

print(len(ls)) ---> 695

ls_set = set(ls)

print(len(ls_set))  ---> 70

print(ls_set)

while using
ls = []

iterate 10atoms and name CA, ls.append((resi, resn))-> Iterate: iterated over 45 atoms.

print(ls)

print(len(ls)) ---> 45

ls_set = set(ls)

print(len(ls_set))  ---> 45

print(ls_set) 

It's because in :

within


“within” finds atoms in the first selection within a cutoff distance of atoms in the second selection.


Usage


selection within distance of selection

So if only some atoms of a residue but not CAs, are within your cutoff distance using:
iterate 10atoms and name CA, ls.append((resi, resn))
will lose them from your list.
Note
Because of the way I used
select 10atoms, chain A within 10 of ios
ios is part of the results too.
